# Javascript Array.remove() by John Resig - why does it enumerate in for-in statement?

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, properties

I just found [John Resig's Array.remove()](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-array-remove/) function. [Looks like his site isn't properly parsing the bb-code so it's hard to read!]

While it's nifty, the problem is that the 'remove()' method enumerates in a for-in statement for every array after loading his code.

For example, after prepending his code, do this:

```
var a = ["a", "b", "c"];
for (i in a)
{
    console.log(i);
}
```

And you get:

```
0
1
2
remove
```

Why don't all the other built-in properties and methods of the Array object enumerate, and is there any way to prevent this happening for the remove() method?

[Here's a jsfiddle...](https://jsfiddle.net/dghm4mrL/)

Comment: Note that that blog post is from almost 9 years ago. It's ancient; generally don't pay attention to anything about JavaScript from that long ago until you get confirmation that it's still relevant.

Comment: @Pointy so there's a better way to remove array elements now?

Comment: The code isn't bad, but the point is that lots and lots of things have changed over the past 9 years. Mr. Resig would not write that code the same way now, I'd bet.

Comment: Why would you use `for-in` on an Array in the first place? Doesn't really make sense. I mean it *sort of* works, but the problems it causes outweigh the benefits, which IMO don't actually exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Object.defineProperty()` to add the method:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "remove", {
  value: function() { ... }
});
```

That will by default leave the "enumerable" flag turned **off** for the property, meaning that it won't show up in `for ... in` loops.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for.  Thanks!  Seriously, if you know of a better/recommended "remove" function, I would love to know about it.  Odd this feature hasn't been added to JS yet - it's quite an obvious and common one, I would think.

Comment: https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/01/04/exploring-javascript-for-in-loops/